# Any way to reduce the amount of concurrent requests to fetch data and cache in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, caching, express, concurrency, redis

I have an Express app which requires very low response rate ~<200ms. Right now we can only get this number but that's a separate topic.

We're planning to fetch a piece of data from the database, if found in Redis return the data if not then fire the request and save that to redis so the next requests can get it from Redis.

I'm running some testing and was wondering if there's a way to reduce the amount of database fetching requests?

For example, currently our application has 300req/s per box. We have six boxes running on AWS. If for the first time that piece of data is not available in Redis, there might be around ~500 requests trying to fetch the data from DB and cache that in Redis. We're trying to reduce that number down. Not sure if there's a way in Node.js or Redis to handle that.

Here's the code that I'm testing.

```
client.getAsync('key').then(function (data) {
  if(data) {
    console.log(data); // Return this data if found
    res.send(data);
  } else {
    // I'm trying to reduce the number of calls for concurrent requests in this block.
    console.log('not found');
    var dataFromDb = // fetch data from DB
    client.set('key', dataFromDb); // Fire and forget 
    res.send('not found'); // Return not found right away
  }
});
```

And I test the call by using `ab`

```
ab -n 20 -c 10 http://localhost:8081/redis
```

This is the results I got

```
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
something
not found
something
something
something
something
something
something
something
something
something
something
```

In this example, there's 7 requests trying to fetch database with the same data and save to Redis.

My question is, is there anyway I can reduce the number of requests down? Because fetching DB is quite slow as of now ~900ms (We're trying to optimize that)

Comment: It depends. For example, you can warm up your cache when it's flushed or destroyed or when you republish the app, you can make a distributed lock when you're fetching data from the DB to allow only one client access it and after that fetch it from redis

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any example I can follow? I'm not familiar with distributed locking.

Comment: there is a redlock algorithm provided by Redis team

Comment: Distributed locks are fine if you actually have more than one Redis instance, but if you just have one, I've found the simple locking mechanism described on [the same page](http://redis.io/topics/distlock) as the distributed lock mechanism works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. I did same thing. I will describe only logic here. Method to fetchCache should return a promise. Also you keep array of { cacheKey, promise }. Each time you send a request - you add key to this array. When next time you need to fetch cache - you check array first and if key there grabbing this promise. Else calling fetchCache.

Here is my code. It works, but probably hard to read. Should give you a basic understanding.

```
class DictTranslatableRepo {

    constructor(model) {
        var self = this;
        self.title = model + "s Repo";

        self.model = models[model];
        self.running = {};
        self.curItems = {};
    }


    *start() {
        var self = this;
        var curItems = yield self.model.findAll();
        _.forEach(curItems, function(row) {
            self.curItems[row.key] = row.value;
        });
    };


    *map(from) {
        var self = this;

        if (from == "") return "";

        if (!_.isUndefined(self.curItems[from])) return self.curItems[from];

        if (_.isUndefined(self.running[from])) {
            self.running[from] = [];
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                self.running[from].push(resolve);

                self.job(from, function(err, to) {       // Main job
                    var callbackArr = self.running[from];
                    delete self.running[from];
                    _.forEach(callbackArr, function(callback) {
                        callback(to);
                    });
                });
            });
        } else {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                self.running[from].push(resolve);
            });
        }
    };


    job(from, callback) {
        var self = this;
        var to = "as shown";
        co(function*() {
            try {
                to = yield translator.translate(from);
                yield self.model.add({key: from, value: to});
                self.curItems[from] = to;
                callback(null, to);
            } catch (err) {
                callback(err);
                //logger.error("Cant translate entity: " + from);
            }
        }).catch(function(err) {
            // Unhandled Error
            callback(new Error(err));
        });
    };

}
```

My `map` method is your fetchCache method.